# Sales force org claiming my custom controller doesn't exist when it quite clearly does

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, help

currently having a bit of an argument with my org during a challenge as to whether or not the custom controller I wrote exists or not, I think it quite clearly does as shown in the screenshot below but my salesforce playground org seems to disagree :( Any Idea why that might be? And yes, I have saved it and even put a space in one of the words to make it purposefully error out so the ui updated, then fixed it and saved it again so I had absolute confirmation that my controller is saved.
[image]

Comment: in your vf page try adding `controller` in place of `standardController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this error because in your VF page it's referred as `standardController`.

Change it as `controller` to fix this error :

```
<apex:page controller="NewCaseListController">
```

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm

Comment: Thanks Rohit, confirmed this fixed the error but I never saw that the requirement of the attribute being named just Controller being pointed out anywhere. Cheers. I do have another question now should I ask here or make a new thread? It relates to an issue I'm having with the output from my controller method not being what was expected despite I triple checked it with debugging and It definitely is (I have screenshots as proof)

Comment: You can ask another question so that anyone from the community can answer.